# Where should I calculate quantities? In my .NET Core Web API or in SQL Server as a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am writing an inventory application with a Reactjs front end and .NET Core Web API on the backend that connects to Microsoft SQL Server.

Where would be the proper place to calculate the quantities on hand? Should I do it in SQL Server as a stored procedure, or in the code of the Web API?

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question as broad as this, you have to weigh up the amount of data you would have to send to the app against doing aggregates in the database.

Comment: Just as a rule of thumb, I try to keep calculations as close to the data as possible.   This reduces the number of touch points and allows you to serve multiple masters in a consistent fashion.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design decision, that could have many "correct" answers.

However, I would say you should have your business logic (like calculating quantities) in the WebApi. Keeping business logic in the main code base, has some immediate benefits, including:

- It's easier to understand the code when the database is just a dumb read/write store.
- It's easier to test the logic using unit tests
- It reduces dependencies to the database engine, making it easier to switch in the future if you have the need

So, keep it in the WebApi if you don't have any compelling arguments against it.

Answer (score 2):

> Where would be the proper place to calculate the quantities on hand?

In SQL Server, typically.

> Should I do it on the SQL server as a stored procedure or in the code of the web API?

If you use [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), you can write the query in the Web API, in C#, and Execute the query on the SQL Server (or optionally fetch the data and process the results in .NET).

A query like:

```
var qty = db.Inventory
            .Where( p => p.ProductID == someId )
            .Sum( i => i.QuantityOnHand );
```

will be executed on the server.  But if you want to execute it on the client instead, you can

```
var qty = db.Inventory.Select( i => new { i.ProductId, i.QuantityOnHand })
                      .ToList()
                      .Where( p => p.ProductID == someId )
                      .Sum( i => i.QuantityOnHand );
```

which will fetch the data from the server and perform the rest of the query on the client.  So you get the ability to *specify* the logic in your application code, and *execute* it either on the client or server.